# Add a button to change to dark mode in html website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have added a button on my site which let's the users change to dark or light mode whenever they want. I added the button with a moon icon on it, but the problem is that I want that the moon icon changes to sun icon when the user is in dark mode. And changes to moon icon when user is in light mode.

```js
function myfunction(e) {
  console.log("you clicked");
  document.documentElement.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
  document.querySelectorAll(".inverted").forEach((result) => {
    result.classList.toggle("invert");
  });
}
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn')
btn.addEventListener('click', myfunction);
```

```css
.dark-mode {
  filter: invert(1) hue-rotate(180deg);
}

.invert {
  filter: invert(1) hue-rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn"><img src='moon.png'></img></button>
```

The .inverted class in js is because I don't want the images to invert their colors.. so I gave all the images a class='inverted'

So, this is what I've done and someone please let me know how I should change the icon to moon and sun depending on the current mode (light or dark)

Thanks!

Comment: Could you use a `background-image` instead? Then you could set the appropriate image URL from your CSS.

Comment: I see no snippet where you change the icon. Just check in what mode the user is and set the icon dynamic. Thats no magic. You nearly have anything together.

Comment: I don't think it's looking good with it as a background image, thanks for the answer though:)

Comment: Thanks, for the answer Marc! But the problem is like it's just 1-2 weeks that I've started web development, so I don't know how to change the icon according to the current mode of the user. So if you could pls elaborate on that.
Thanks!:)

Answer (score 0):

You could add the sun as another image to the button and change the visibility of the two images via your `.dark-mode` css class.

So whenever the `.dark-mode` class is present the moon gets hidden and the sun gets shown.

```js
function myfunction(e) {
  console.log("you clicked");
  document.documentElement.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
  document.querySelectorAll(".inverted").forEach((result) => {
    result.classList.toggle("invert");
  });
}
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn')
btn.addEventListener('click', myfunction);
```

```css
.dark-mode {
  filter: invert(1) hue-rotate(180deg);
}

.invert {
  filter: invert(1) hue-rotate(180deg);
}


/* button handling */

.moon {
  display: block;
}

.sun {
  display: none;
}

.dark-mode .moon {
  display: none;
}

.dark-mode .sun {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">
  <img class="moon" src="moon.png" alt="moon"></img>
  <img class="sun" src="sun.png" alt="sun"></img>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go with the CSS approach as in @Fabian's answer. If you would like to go with JS, you could simply use a flag to indicate whether or not the user switched to dark mode, and dynamically set the icon based on it.

```
let isDarkMode = document.documentElement.classList.contains("dark-mode");
function myfunction(e) {
    document.documentElement.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
    document.querySelectorAll(".inverted").forEach((result) => {
        result.classList.toggle("invert");
    });
    e.currentTarget.querySelector("img").src = isDarkMode ? "sun.png" : "moon.png";
 }
```

Comment: @Khushhal - I have edited the answer to be more accurate and concise. Please review the changes.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myfunction(e) {
  const doc = document.documentElement
  doc.classList.toggle("dark-mode");

  document.querySelectorAll(".inverted").forEach((result) => {
    result.classList.toggle("invert");
  });



  const img = e.currentTarget.querySelector('img')
  const label = e.currentTarget.querySelector('span')
  if (doc.classList.contains('dark-mode')) {
    img.src = 'sun.png'
    label.innerHTML = 'Light mode'
  } else {
    img.src = 'moon.png'
    label.innerHTML = 'Dark mode'
  }

}
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn')
btn.addEventListener('click', myfunction);
```

```css
.dark-mode {
  filter: invert(1) hue-rotate(180deg);
}

.invert {
  filter: invert(1) hue-rotate(180deg);
}

'
```

```html
<button class="btn">
  <img src='moon.png' alt="" />
  <span>Dark mode</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below reference for the toggle button from light mode to dark mode and dark mode to light mode.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.toggle-checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

.toggle-slot {
  position: relative;
  height: 10em;
  width: 20em;
  border: 5px solid #e4e7ec;
  border-radius: 10em;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 25px #e4e7ec;
  transition: background-color 250ms;
}

.toggle-checkbox:checked ~ .toggle-slot {
  background-color: #374151;
}

.toggle-button {
  transform: translate(11.75em, 1.75em);
  position: absolute;
  height: 6.5em;
  width: 6.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ffeccf;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 0.75em #ffbb52;
  transition: background-color 250ms, border-color 250ms, transform 500ms cubic-bezier(.26,2,.46,.71);
}

.toggle-checkbox:checked ~ .toggle-slot .toggle-button {
  background-color: #485367;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 0.75em white;
  transform: translate(1.75em, 1.75em);
}

.sun-icon {
  position: absolute;
  height: 6em;
  width: 6em;
  color: #ffbb52;
}

.sun-icon-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  height: 6em;
  width: 6em;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(2em, 2em) rotate(15deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transition: opacity 150ms, transform 500ms cubic-bezier(.26,2,.46,.71);
}

.toggle-checkbox:checked ~ .toggle-slot .sun-icon-wrapper {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(3em, 2em) rotate(0deg);
}

.moon-icon {
  position: absolute;
  height: 6em;
  width: 6em;
  color: white;
}

.moon-icon-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  height: 6em;
  width: 6em;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(11em, 2em) rotate(0deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transition: opacity 150ms, transform 500ms cubic-bezier(.26,2.5,.46,.71);
}

.toggle-checkbox:checked ~ .toggle-slot .moon-icon-wrapper {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(12em, 2em) rotate(-15deg);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://code.iconify.design/1/1.0.4/iconify.min.js">   </script>
</head>
<label>
  <input class='toggle-checkbox' type='checkbox'>
  <div class='toggle-slot'>
    <div class='sun-icon-wrapper'>
      <div class="iconify sun-icon" data-icon="feather-sun" data-inline="false"></div>
    </div>
    <div class='toggle-button'></div>
    <div class='moon-icon-wrapper'>
      <div class="iconify moon-icon" data-icon="feather-moon" data-inline="false"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</label>
```